# Show PDF in Custom Layout?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I want to design and an android application , which consists of Activity in which I am creating PDF file with iText. After click of button from same activity I want to show the content of that PDF file with different buttons are present.
 Also I don't want to use the 
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` which will display list of available PDF support application.

So can you please suggest some solution how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem with Android is that WebView widget doesn't support PDF natively as the one in iOS does. AFAIK there is no native solution for this, you'll have to try third-party libraries and last time I checked open-source solutions with lesser licenses for this they were buggy, not-documented, and difficult to integrate...

Comment: @thelawnmowerman: I have tried using different third-party library like droidText.0.2.jar,PdfViewer.jar. but no luck it is opening same way as Intent. :(

Comment: You would need an SDK that can view PDF. For example, PDFTron PDFNet (http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/android_pdf_library.html) can be used for both reading/vieweing and creating/editing PDFs.

Comment: @Ika:that SDK seems to be not free